crank arm with 15mm diamond holes
I have a stationary bike that was given to me. The threads for the pedals are stripped, so I was trying to replace the crank arms.
Both arms are diamond hole types, I managed to get them off, but I cannot find a replacement. Most website do not specify the size of the square hole, and if they do, all I can find are 14mm holes. I have ordered two sets to try out and both are 14mm, while the square "pegs"(?) on my bike are 15mm wide (measured from face to face).
Is there such a thing as 15mm diamond hole crank arms? Do I have to replace the bottom bracket as well so I have a more standard size?
pictures of the bottom bracket:




Post a photo - can you replace the Bottom bracket?

Definitely post photos of the bottom bracket/crankarm area. These are needed to formulate accurate answers.

By Diamond, do you mean square?   Square taper is totally a normal cycling thing, but there's nothing that is diamond-shaped.

@Criggie sometimes "diamond" is used to specify the orientation of the square hole with respect to the crank arm. It's only usually an issue if buying single replacement cranks, so it's not a common term

There was a post on this in a similar vein a few months backs. Basically the manufacturer has proprietary cranks that cost $200.

thank you all for your suggestions. I have added photos to my post

They're also threaded in an unusual way, so you'd need cranks that can take nuts.

What brand and model is it? Maybe the maker sells parts

@mattnz based on photos, this exercycle has a BB shaft inside two ball bearing races and not a standard bottom bracket.  The plate with weld AND bolts through it looks kinda permanent.   Helicoiling both cranks seems like the cheapest option.

It does look like a case of reinventing the wheel, or near enough. Unicycles use a hub with a spindle with bearing races, which might be similar but won't be compatible. The power transfer off the hub is hidden in there somewhere

It may be possible to get cranks to fit, but it won't be easy or cheap.  Instead it's possible to get the pedal thread restored in the cranks you have.  The process is called fitting a helicoil.  While you can buy the parts and tools yourself, for a one-off it's cheaper to send them away (unless you can find a bike shop with the kit).  The cost, when I looked into it, was about the same as a set of cranks. The kits are particularly expensive because of the left hand thread used in the left pedal, which increases the parts count; the thread pitch is also an uncommon one.
It's possible these cranks use the smaller 1/2" threaded pedal standard; most adult bikes use 9/16".  That's another thing to check.  The difference isn't enough to get the smaller size retapped to the larger directly. Given how non-standard the rest of it is, I wouldn't even rule out something even stranger.

Should note the left crank has a left-hand thread, so its  a job that requires specialized tools. Most bike shops will have the tools. Many (most?) engineering shops won't have the left hand 9/16 taps for the heli coils.

Worse - bicycle pedals use 20 TPI 9/16", and not the industry standard 18TPI.  Which is why normal helicoil kits for 18 TPI cost a tenth as much as bike-specific ones.   Its priced up into the realm of dedicated bike shops, not the home-mechanic.

@mattnz you're right, that's a point that needs to be made (rather than assumed as I did)

Thank you for your answer, I will follow your advice and try to get the pedal threads repaired instead.
